# Can I write the subgroup $\langle 7 \rangle$ of $U(11)$ this way?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have the multiplicative group $U(11)$. Now 7 is a primitive root modulo $11$. So, $\langle 7 \rangle = U(11)$ Can I write $$\langle 7 \rangle=\{7^{10} = 1,7, 7^2=5, 7^3=2, 7^4=3, 7^5=10, 7^6=4, 7^7=6, 7^8=9, 7^9=8\} $$ the subgroup generated by 7 as above ? I mean the equality is valid here, Right ?

Comment: Of course we understand what you mean, but you need to realize that what you really mean is $7^2 \equiv 5 \bmod 11$ rather than $7^2 = 5$, and writing $7^2=5$ can cause confusion, depending on the context. I sometimes find it helpful to introduce a notation $=_n$ and write $7^2 =_{11} 5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's fine. You could use other numbers, too, since $11$ is prime.

Comment: I mean the equality is valid here, Right ?

Comment: Yes, @gaufler. Some conventions require you to write, say, for example, $$[7]_{11}=\{x\in\Bbb Z: 11\mid 7-x\}$$ instead of $7$, but that's nitpicking.